# How to hide whitespace characters in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have accidentally pressed some buttons on my keyboard. And now Eclipse is showing this sign in the end of each line.

[image]

Honestly, I dont know how this sign is called. How to turn off showing this sign?

Comment: Would you mind editing your title to "How to hide whitespace characters" so it's easier to find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the "Show Whitespace Characters" toggle button on the toolbar, shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: I don't have this toolbar - how do I add it ?

Answer (score 4):

Go to `Window > Preferences > General > Text Editors` then uncheck `Show whitespace characters` and click `OK`.

If you're using the [Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/) plugin, just run the `:set list!` command and it also disappears.